# iPhone Status Bar for custom message ala Evernote, In-Call, etc

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, statusbar

I am trying to find how to implement a custom message on the status bar, something like the Evernote "Downloading changes..." message seen [here](http://legobuff.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/photo.jpg).

Is this a private API call?  Any suggestions or pointers?

Comment: Your image link is now displaying Not Found. Looks like it's hosted on your domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pretty much looks like a label put on top of the view there and then the table view right below it , should not be tough to do...

```
    UILabel *label=...
    label.text=@"My Text"
    //maybe justify here so  its c enters
    //set the rectangle bounds to what they need to be 
//for the example there it would probably be (0,0,320,5) or something like that 
//and the tableview w ould be at (0,5,320,455)
```

Comment: I agree, it looks like it's part of the normal visible area.  You'll want to adjust the background color of the label in Interface Builder and the color of the font as well.

Comment: huh, i was hoping that there was an api to tie into, the behavior is like when you are on a call, tethered, or recording a voice memo, the message is flashing and animates on show and hide.  

Guess i'll go the label route for now.

Comment: thre isnt an api for that purpose, u can recreate what you want to do pretty easily

Answer (score 4):

You should have a look at [MTStatusBarOverlay](https://github.com/myell0w/MTStatusBarOverlay).

Answer (score 0):

As @sam has pointed out, MTStatusBarOverlay is a good choice and I'm currently using it in my apps.  *However* I just found something that exactly fits what the original poster (and I) have been looking for.  I love all the folks on GitHub who see some cool UI element in a new app and recreate it for the masses ... this is one of those cases.  Awesomeness!
[Tweetbot-Like Alert Panels (Blog)](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/ios-code-tweetbot-like-alertpanels/), and the repository is [MKInfoPanelDemo at Github](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKInfoPanelDemo).

Comment: I too think MTStatusBarOverlay is a good choice ;) (I'm the author). I also like Mugunth's MKInfoPanelDemo. In fact I like it that much that I first send some Pull Request and then decided to create my own repository that builds upon MKInfoPanelDemo but adds some functionality (e.g. you can specify the colors/fonts etc.) and tries to come as close to TweetBots notifications as possible (style-wise). Take a look:
https://github.com/myell0w/MTInfoPanel

Comment: I've had my eye on your fork/repo and I'm very interested in putting it to use.  Seems much more flexible.